# Build queries from table/column names stored in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `TABLES_IDS` that looks like this:

```
Table_ID  Table_Name  Table_Column
--------  ----------  ------------
100       Attributes  Attribute_id
101       NewSamples  Section_id
...
```

I have a "first query" that returns several values of `Table_Name`. This `Table_Name` is actually the name of another table, and `Table_Column` is a column. I need to do the following:

1. For every obtained `Table_Name`, I need to retrieve corresponding `Table_Column` value.
2. Using `Table_Name` and `Table_Column`, create a new sql query that looks e.g. as

   ```
   SELECT FROM Table_Name WHERE Table_Column = 12345
   ```
3. Automatically repeat everyting for every `Table_Name` returned by the very first query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to run a series of queries based on the table / column name stored in this table. You can't reference table and column names as variables or coming from the result of a query or expression, so you need to use dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' 
  + QUOTENAME(Table_Name) + ' WHERE ' 
  + QUOTENAME(Table_Column) + ' = 12345;'
FROM dbo.TABLES_IDS
-- WHERE...
;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```